# C - fork() and exec() together

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec

I'm writing a exercise program that uses fork() and is supposed to use one of exec()s. I managed to write a short code, that looks like:

```
        ...
        int v1 = fork();
        int v2 = fork();
        if (v1 == 0)
        {
              //probably exec should be here
        }
        int status1, child1 = wait(&status1);
        int status2, child2 = wait(&status2);

        printf("%d \t %d \t\n", getpid(), v1);
        printf("%d \t %d \t\n", getpid(), v2);
        printf("%d \t\n", getpid());
        printf("\n");
```

and when I execute that, I'm getting:

```
5721     5720
5721     0
5721

5722     0
5722     0
5722

5720     0
5720     5722
5720

5719     5720
5719     5721
5719              //this one looks correct according to example in exercise
```

My question is: will exec function fill those zeros with correct pids of children as it is in the last 3 lines and if that's right, how should I correctly use one of exec()s then? If not, why there are zeros in the middle section then? I was struggling with that for few days and can't figure it out, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: how many childs do you want to have and also what do you want the exec function to do in the chilf ?

Comment: I want exec to execute the same code with argument lowered by 1 for the first child and lowered by 2 for the second child

Comment: I give you an example down below check it out for how you call exec

Comment: did you check it out ?

Comment: Since your code doesn't show `main()`, let alone any command-line argument handling, it is hard to know what you're planning to do. You should create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). Then we can see better. As it stands, all the processes (parent, two child processes and one grandchild process) go through the waiting and printing code. You should arguably print the data from the `wait()` calls — along with the PID of the process.

Comment: The `exec()` function does not change the PID of the process that executes it, but it does change the program that is run.  The zeros will still be zeros — they indicate that the process printing the value is a child, or the child of a child.

Comment: The exec call changes the code being executed by the process. What happens after exec depends on the code of the program that was passed to exec as a parameter.